# Create new tab name via inputbox if there is already a duplicate that was populated via combobox

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I haven't been able to find this answer elsewhere on the forum, but I have a combobox that creates a tab name based on the inputs selected. The problem is that there is the opportunity for duplicate tab names. I would like to create a macro that creates an inputbox if there is a duplicate tab already in existence for the user to type in their own naming convention for the new tab instead.

Here is the current VBA code that populates a new tab based on the form selections, which works unless there is a duplicate.

```
Dim strNewName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
If CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxPayer.Value = "Other" Then
strNewName = CreateNewVBA.TextBoxOtherPayer.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxLOB.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxContractType.Value
Else
strNewName = CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxPayer.Value & CreateNewVBA.TextBoxOtherPayer.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxLOB.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxContractType.Value
End If
If strNewName <> "" Then
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = strNewName
End If
```

If this form creates a duplicate then I want it to create an inputbox that says "A similar contract already exists. Please enter a name for the new VBA.", and I want that inputbox to populate the new tab name.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

### Add and Rename a New Worksheet

```vb
Sub CreateNewContract()
     
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create New Contract"
     
    Const NAME_DELIMITER As String = " "
    Const DELETE_IF_INVALID_NAME As Boolean = True
    Const SAVE_WORKBOOK As Boolean = False
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     
    ' Build the contract name.
     
    Dim LeftName As String, NewName As String
    
    With CreateNewVBA
        LeftName = .ComboBoxPayer.Value
        NewName = .TextBoxOtherPayer.Value & NAME_DELIMITER _
            & .ComboBoxLOB.Value & NAME_DELIMITER & .ComboBoxContractType.Value
    End With

    If StrComp(LeftName, "Other", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not equal
        NewName = LeftName & NewName
    End If
        
    ' Check if the contract name is not taken.
        
    Dim sh As Object, OtherName As Variant, IsNameNotTaken As Boolean
    
    Do Until IsNameNotTaken = True
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sh = wb.Sheets(NewName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If sh Is Nothing Then
            IsNameNotTaken = True
        Else
            OtherName = Application.InputBox( _
                "The chosen contract name is already taken." & vbLf _
                & "Please enter a different one.", PROC_TITLE, sh.Name)
            If VarType(OtherName) = vbBoolean Then
                MsgBox "Canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Sub
            Else
                NewName = OtherName
                Set sh = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    
    Loop
    
    ' Add a new worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    ' Attempt to rename the new worksheet.
    
    Dim ErrorNumber As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
        ws.Name = NewName
        ErrorNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check whether the new worksheet could be renamed.
    
    If ErrorNumber = 0 Then
        If SAVE_WORKBOOK Then
            If Len(wb.Path) > 0 Then
                wb.Save
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox "Created contract """ & NewName & """.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        If DELETE_IF_INVALID_NAME Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        MsgBox "The name """ & NewName & """ is invalid.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Validating the user input as a valid sheet name before creating a new sheet is necessary.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim strNewName As String, strInput As String
    Dim strShts As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxPayer.Value = "Other" Then
        strNewName = CreateNewVBA.TextBoxOtherPayer.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxLOB.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxContractType.Value
    Else
        strNewName = CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxPayer.Value & CreateNewVBA.TextBoxOtherPayer.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxLOB.Value & " " & CreateNewVBA.ComboBoxContractType.Value
    End If
    ' strNewName = "Sheet2" ' Testing
    If strNewName <> "" Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            strShts = strShts & "|" & UCase(ws.Name) & "|"
        Next
        If InStr(strShts, "|" & UCase(strNewName) & "|") > 0 Then
            strInput = VBA.InputBox("A similar contract already exists. Please enter a name for the new VBA.")
            If Len(strInput) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "No input!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf InStr(strShts, "|" & UCase(strInput) & "|") > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Duplicated sheet name", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                strNewName = strInput
            End If
        End If
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = strNewName
    End If
End Sub
```